# Can't resize UIViewController using custom segue and Storyboard

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, resize, ios8, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom `tabBar` app using custom **segue** with a problem on the size of the `destinationViewController` always loading in **fullscreen** and not at the size I defined in the attributes Inspector.

I set the Size of the `ViewController` as Freeform in the Simulated Metrics and at Simulated Size ate the Size Inspector I defined the width as 1024 and height as 693. I also unchecked the Resize View from **NIB** even though I am not using **.xib** files.

I have tested the project on both Simulator and real device, but does not work.

When I click the button it shows the `destinationViewController` but it hides the `TabBar`, which of course should not happen.

The pictures shows better what I am facing:

[image: Attributes Inspector]

[image: Size Inspector]

[image: First ViewController]

[image: Segued ViewController]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution. The problem was actually with the perform() function which I was using this way:

```
override func perform() {
    var src = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
    var dst = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    src.presentViewController(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

And the fix is that I changed the presentViewController line with this one:

```
override func perform() {
    var src = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
    var dst = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    src.view .addSubview(dst.view)
}
```

Now everything works fine!!!